# How to get a list of row indexes in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to get a list of indexes of rows according to the rule "value in second column == 1)

For example, from this dataframe

```
   1 2
1  1 1
2  1 1
3  1 1
4  0 1
5  0 0
6  0 1
```

I need a list

```
[1,2,3,4,6]
```

I just switched to R from Python and I am a bit lost within the different data types.

Comment: `which(df$Col2 == 1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
which(!!df$`2`) # applicable only if you only have values 0 and 1 in column 2
```

or

```
which(df$`2`==1)
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(`1` = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `2` = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: I think OP really wants a list.

Comment: If it needs a list, just do `as.list`